# Is HMAC still needed if encrypted data is always saved and retrieved locally

Tags: encryption, hmac

My understanding of HMAC is that it can help to verify the integrity of encrypted data before the data is processed i.e. it can be used to determine whether or not the data being sent to a decryption routine has been modified in any way.

That being the case, is there any advantage in incorporating it into an encryption scheme if the data is never transmitted outside of the application generating it? My use case is quite simple - a user submits data (in plaintext) to the scripts I've written to store customer details. My scripts then encrypt this data and save it to the database, and my scripts then provide a way for the user to retrieve the data and decrypt it based on the record ID they supply. There is no way for my users to send encrypted data directly to the decryption routine and I don't need to provide an external API.

Therefore, is it reasonable to assume that there is a chain of trust in the application by default because the same application is responsible for writing and retrieving the data? If I add HMAC to this scheme, is it redundant in this context or is it best practice to always implement HMAC regardless of the context? I'm intending to use the Defuse library but I'd like to understand what the benefit of HMAC is to my project.

Thanks in advance for any advice or input :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should understand that there are attacks that allow an attacker to modify encrypted data without decrypting it. See [Is there an attack that can modify ciphertext while still allowing it to be decrypted?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46704/is-there-an-attack-that-can-modify-ciphertext-while-still-allowing-it-to-be-decr) on Security.SE and [Malleability attacks against encryption without authentication](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/malleability-attacks-against-encryption-without-authentication) on Crypto.SE. If an attacker gets write access to the encrypted data -- even without any decryption keys -- they could cause significant havoc.

You say that the encrypted data is "never transmitted outside of the application generating it" but in the next two sentences you say that you "save it to the database" which appears (to me) to be something of a contradiction. Trusting the processing of encrypted data in memory is one thing, but trusting its serialization to disk, especially if done by another program (such as a database system) and/or on a separate physical machine (now or in the future, as the system evolves).

The significant question here is: would it ever be a possible for an attacker to modify or replace the encrypted data with alternate encrypted data, without access to the application and keys? If the attacker is an insider and runs the program as a normal user, then it's not generally possible to defend your data: anything the program allows the attacker to do is on the table. However, HMAC is relevant when write access to the data is possible for a non-user (or for a user in excess of their normal permissions). If the database is compromised, an attacker could possibly modify data with impunity, even without access to the application itself. Using HMAC verification severely limits the attacker's ability to modify the data usefully, even if they get write access.

Comment: Thanks for that. So what you're saying is that I cannot automatically assume that the data I encrypt in my application will not be modified in any way before it gets saved to the database? That makes me think that HMAC is useful for data integrity (that is, did what I send to the database get saved correctly). Without subverting the application (i.e. compromising it) there is no way for the user to directly write encrypted data - the record update routines will encrypt any data sent to the script and the user cannot call the encryption/decryption routines directly.

Comment: @NoelWhitemore Can you conceptualize an attack where an attacker could write to the database disk without the ability to run the application? If the answer is "yes" or could possibly become "yes" in the future (i.e., access to the database is independent from the application -- e.g., the database can be accessed over the network) then HMAC will defend the integrity of your data. There are plenty of ways to meaningfully modify encrypted data without decrypting it (flipping bits, repeating blocks); that is largely what HMAC defends against.

Comment: The answer to that question is probably "no" but I understand your point and one day somebody might take my application and put it on a different server, or put multiple copies of that application on different servers and talk to a centralised database server. In that case, HMAC would be useful because it would be enable the application to verify whether it generated the encrypted data or not.

Comment: @NoelWhitemore I suppose in the end, it's about risk/cost assessment: how expensive is it to implement this protection (in terms of dev time, upkeep time, training time) versus the risk of it being an issue (in terms of impact and likelihood). Though the level risk is probably low, the cost to do it appears to be low as well.

Comment: I think I only need to quantify the cost in terms of performance overhead. If it takes 30 seconds to generate a HMAC each time the user saves some data then clearly that's not going to work, but if the performance overhead is neglible then there's no real problem. The encryption/decryption routines will hopefully only need to be written and tested once, and any new people that work on the system shouldn't need to make any changes to it. My test scripts do what Defuse does but without the HMAC functionality, so that's the only piece of the puzzle that I'm missing.

Comment: @apsillers Another risk to consider is, "How hard (costly) would it be to add later if the situation changes and it's now needed?" If the cost of building it in now is low and the cost of adding it later is high, then it may also be better to just err on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

My OCD usually dictates that implementing HMAC is always good practice, if for no other reason, to remove the warning from logs.

In your case I do not believe there is a defined upside to implementing HMAC other than ensuring the integrity of the plain text submission. Your script may encrypt the data but it would not be useful in the unlikely event that bad data is passed to it.

Comment: Thanks. As apsillers mentioned, I've automatically assumed that a chain of trust exists between my PHP script and the database which (theoretically) could be exploited. All of the encryption/decryption is done within the application though - for me, this means that verifying the integrity of the encrypted data would be useful in the unlikely event that someone found a way to exploit the link between PHP and the database server.